# Program to press a key at timed intervals

Tags: keyboard

I was wondering if there was an open source program that would allow me to have a certain keystroke/key combination pressed every say, two seconds or so.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is an open source program to create fake keyboard and mouse inputs for GNU/Linux. It is called [**Xdotool**](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) [image: Install Xdotool].

To press a key (in this example 'a') every two seconds you can use a script like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  xdotool key a
  sleep 2
done
```

If you make this script executable and add it to Startup Applications it will press 'a' every two seconds.

[Here is the documentation for Xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml)

[And here is the specific part on keyboard commands](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml#keyboard_commands)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Logitech keyboard, there is a package called "g15macro" in the Ubuntu repo that is useful. Otherwise there are other open source applications such as "[xmacro](http://xmacro.sourceforge.net/)" and "[xnee](http://www.sandklef.com/xnee/)".